# Grep inside all files created within date range

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find, grep, date-range

I am on the Ubuntu OS. I want to grep a word (say XYZ) inside all log files which are created within date range 28-may-2012 to 30-may-2012.

How do I do that?

Comment: A related question in Server Fault: http://serverfault.com/q/122824/36963

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is a little different from Banthar's solution, but it will work with versions of `find` that don't support `-newermt` and it shows how to use the `xargs` command, which is a very useful tool.

You can use the `find` command to locate files "of a certain age".  This will find all files modified between 5 and 10 days ago:

```
 find /directory -type f -mtime -10 -mtime +5
```

To then search those files for a string:

```
 find /directory -type f -mtime -10 -mtime +5 -print0 |
   xargs -0 grep -l expression
```

You can also use the `-exec` switch, but I find `xargs` more readable (and it will often perform better, too, but possibly not in this case).

(Note that the `-0` flag is there to let this command operate on files with embedded spaces, such as `this is my filename`.)

**Update for question in comments**

When you provide multiple expressions to `find`, they are ANDed together.  E.g., if you ask for:

```
find . -name foo -size +10k
```

...`find` will only return files that are both (a) named `foo` *and* (b) larger than 10 kbytes.  Similarly, if you specify:

```
find . -mtime -10 -mtime +5
```

...`find` will only return files that are (a) newer than 10 days ago *and* (b) older than 5 days ago.

For example, on my system it is currently:

```
$ date
Fri Aug 19 12:55:21 EDT 2016
```

I have the following files:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 lars lars 0 Aug 15 00:00 file1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 lars lars 0 Aug 10 00:00 file2
-rw-rw-r--. 1 lars lars 0 Aug  5 00:00 file3
```

If I ask for "files modified more than 5 days ago (`-mtime +5`) I get:

```
$ find . -mtime +5
./file3
./file2
```

But if I ask for "files modified more than 5 days ago but less than 10 days ago" (`-mtime +5 -mtime -10`), I get:

```
$ find . -mtime +5 -mtime -10
./file2
```

Comment: Can someone please explain how specifying -mtime twice is used to specify a range? Specifically, why a negative number for the first occurence, and a positive number for the second? Either I don't understand it, or it's not working on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. It's not discussed in the man page that I'm seeing.

Comment: @battey, I've updated my answer with a response to your question.

Answer (score 21):

Combine grep with [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```
find -newermt "28 May 2012" -not -newermt "30 May 2012" -exec grep XYZ \{\} \;
```

Comment: This `-newermt` option seems undocumented - it does not appear in the link neither in my man pages. However, it is wonderful! How did you discovered it?

Comment: @brandizzi It's under `-newerXY`.

Answer (score -1):

`find` doesn't seem to have options where you can specify specific dates for timestamp comparison (at least the version on my laptop doesn't - there may be other versions and/or other tools that perform similarly), so you'll have to use the number of days. So, as of 2012/06/05, you want to find files newer than 9 days but older than 6 days:

```
find . -type f -ctime -9 -ctime +6 -print0 | xargs -0 grep XYZ
```

Comment: Why not `-mtime` (modification time)? `-ctime` is for status time (whatever that is).