# How to display only files last modified during two chosen months?

Tags: linux

I am trying to filter my output to display only files created in "Jan" and "Feb". Is there a way to do this without using grep?

Would need to be able to switch from "Jan" and "Feb" to "Jan" and "Mar" etc..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898154/grep-inside-all-files-created-within-date-range

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grep inside all files created within date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898154/grep-inside-all-files-created-within-date-range)

Comment: every Jan/Feb or last Jan/Feb or Jan/Feb 2018?

Comment: January 2018 February 2018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
find . -newermt "31 Dec 2017" -not -newermt "28 Feb 2018"
```

or for your specific need:

```
find . -newermt "31 Dec 2017" -not -newermt "28 Feb 2018" -size +30M -printf '%s %p\n' | numfmt --to=iec | sort -h
```

or if you want to keep your command :

```
find . -newermt "31 Dec 2017" -not -newermt "28 Feb 2018" -size +30M -print0 |
xargs -0 ls -lh | sort -h
```

Check :

```
man find | less +/'-newerXY reference'
```

Comment: My current command is "find / -size +30M 2> /dev/null | xargs ls -lh | sort -n". Where would I place that?

Comment: Added version close to your try

Comment: Thank you again for your help, always appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

```
touch -d 1/1/2018 jan
touch -d 3/1/2018 mar
find . -type f -cnewer jan ! -cnewer mar -ls
```

ls is only used for control purpose. -type f might be a wanted restriction or not. `xargs -ls lh` can be omitted by using finds -printf format, see the manpage for the multiple options.